# How to encode jwtToken from es256 pem files java

Tags: java, jwt

I have private and public key `.pem` files that are created within ES256 algorithm. I want to sign JWT token with private key that I can later check with public key.

On [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) I found that there are multiple libs that support ES256: jose4j, nimbus-jose-jwt, jjwt, fusionauth-jwt,  vertx-auth-jwt. Unfortunately I'm unable to find any examples that load keys from pem file and create JWT token.

**Example N1:**

I imported pem file into .keystore with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ES256-public-key.pem -inkey ES256-private-key.pem -out ~/keystore.p12 -name selfsigned -nocerts
```

I tried jose4j with the following code:

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

store.load(new FileInputStream("/home/andrew/keystore.p12"), "test".toCharArray());
Key key = store.getKey("selfsigned", "test".toCharArray());

JsonWebEncryption jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();
jwe.setPayload("Hello World!");
jwe.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(KeyManagementAlgorithmIdentifiers.ECDH_ES_A256KW);
jwe.setEncryptionMethodHeaderParameter(ContentEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifiers.AES_128_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256);
jwe.setKey(key);
String serializedJwe = jwe.getCompactSerialization();
System.out.println("Serialized Encrypted JWE: " + serializedJwe);
jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();
jwe.setAlgorithmConstraints(new AlgorithmConstraints(AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.WHITELIST,
    KeyManagementAlgorithmIdentifiers.ECDH_ES_A256KW));
jwe.setContentEncryptionAlgorithmConstraints(new AlgorithmConstraints(AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.WHITELIST,
    ContentEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifiers.AES_128_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256));
jwe.setKey(key);
jwe.setCompactSerialization(serializedJwe);
System.out.println("Payload: " + jwe.getPayload());
```

It throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jose4j.lang.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl to java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey
    at org.jose4j.jwx.KeyValidationSupport.castKey(KeyValidationSupport.java:64)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.EcdhKeyAgreementAlgorithm.validateEncryptionKey(EcdhKeyAgreementAlgorithm.java:188)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.EcdhKeyAgreementWithAesKeyWrapAlgorithm.validateEncryptionKey(EcdhKeyAgreementWithAesKeyWrapAlgorithm.java:73)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getCompactSerialization(JsonWebEncryption.java:264)
    at com.icthh.A.main(A.java:30)
```

I don't even get why it requires public key to create JWT token.

**Example N2**

```
    private static void nimbus() throws IOException, JOSEException {
        JWSObject jwsObject = new JWSObject(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.ES256),
            new Payload("Hello, world!"));

// We need a 256-bit key for HS256 which must be pre-shared

        byte[] sharedKey = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("/home/andrew/ES256-private-key.pem"));
// Apply the HMAC to the JWS object
        jwsObject.sign(new MACSigner(sharedKey));

// Output in URL-safe format
        System.out.println(jwsObject.serialize());
    }
```

This throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException: The "ES256" algorithm is not supported by the JWS signer
    at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.ensureJWSSignerSupport(JWSObject.java:269)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.sign(JWSObject.java:318)
    at com.icthh.A.main(A.java:57)
```

**Example N3**:

jjwt  - this library seems to be good for android I'm not even sure that it's able to sign token, since android is a client.

What I want to find is complete example how to create signed JWT token from ES256 private and public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using [auth0-java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt)

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.util.Date;


    KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    //
    store.load(new FileInputStream("/home/andrew/keystore.p12"), "test".toCharArray());
    ECPrivateKey pk = (ECPrivateKey) store.getKey("selfsigned", "test".toCharArray());

    Algorithm algorithmHS = Algorithm.ECDSA256(null, pk);
    String token = JWT.create()
        .withSubject("")
        .withExpiresAt(new Date())
        .withNotBefore(new Date())
        .withIssuer("issuer")
        .withClaim("roles", "b")
        .withClaim("keys", "b")
        .sign(algorithmHS);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you actually want. In your question you create an encrypted token (JWE) and in your answer you create a signed token (JWS)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have low understanding of how actually this all thing works. I probably mean signing. I need the same as [spring-security-jwt:JwtHelper.encode](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/JwtHelper.java#L92-L94) method does. It says encode, it was in my original question.

Comment: That's why I wrote `encode` in my origin question and someone edited for encrypt ;)

Comment: yes, I edited it, because despite talking about encode your code contains `JsonWebEncryption jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();` which seams to be reason enough to think you want an encrypted token (JWE)